# MVC4 with EF Migration not working! Database is Empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-migration

I had this error whenever I tried to open my User tab on my website: "Cannot attach the file ‘{0}' as database '{1}'" so I fixed it by using

```
sqllocaldb.exe stop v11.0

sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0
```

in the developer command prompt.

Now I'm able to open up my user tab on my site but my Migration didn't work since my database containing users is empty

I tried  `enable-migrations -contexttypename IssueContext` and `update-database`
but errors in the image is shown:(Open in new tab to see)

UPDATE NEW ERROR: Open in new tab to see!

[image]

Configuration.cs (seed method)

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext context)
        {
            var users = new List<User>
            {
                new User { FirstMidName = "Jason",   LastName = "Wan", 
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18") },
                new User { FirstMidName = "Andy", LastName = "Domagas",    
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18") },
                new User { FirstMidName = "Denis",   LastName = "Djohar",     
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18") },
                new User { FirstMidName = "Christine",   LastName = "West",     
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18") },

            };


            users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.LastName, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var categories = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category {CategoryID = 0001, Title = "Desktop"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0002, Title = "Mobile"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0003, Title = "Menzits"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0004, Title = "XMPRO"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0005, Title = "Con-X"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0006, Title = "Promapp"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0007, Title = "QGIS"},
            };
            categories.ForEach(s => context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Title, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var tickets = new List<Ticket>
            {
                new Ticket { 
                    UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID, 
                    CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.Title == "Con-X" ).CategoryID, 
                    Issue = ("Test Error 1"),
                    Priority = Priority.High 
                },
                new Ticket { 
                    UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID, 
                    CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.Title == "Desktop" ).CategoryID, 
                    Issue = ("Test Error 2"),
                    Priority = Priority.Med
                },
            };

            foreach (Ticket e in tickets)
            {
                var ticketInDataBase = context.Tickets.Where(
                    s =>
                        s.User.UserID == e.UserID &&
                        s.Category.CategoryID == e.CategoryID).SingleOrDefault();
                if (ticketInDataBase == null)
                {
                    context.Tickets.Add(e);
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();


            var departments = new List<Department>
            {
                new Department { DepartmentID = 1, Name = "IT", Users = new List<User>()},
                new Department { DepartmentID = 2, Name = "Admin", Users = new List<User>() },
                new Department { DepartmentID = 3, Name = "Human Resources", Users = new List<User>()},
                new Department { DepartmentID = 4, Name = "Mechanics" , Users = new List<User>()},
                new Department { DepartmentID = 5, Name = "Directors" , Users = new List<User>()},
                new Department { DepartmentID = 6, Name = "Operations", Users = new List<User>()}


            };
            departments.ForEach(s => context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
            context.SaveChanges();


            var administrator = new List<Administrator>
            {
                new Administrator {AdminID = 1, AdminRole = "Administrator LVL1", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 1),
                Tickets = new List<Ticket>() },
                new Administrator {AdminID = 2, AdminRole = "Administrator LVL2", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 2),
                Tickets = new List<Ticket>() },
                new Administrator {AdminID = 3, AdminRole = "Administrator LVL3", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 3),
                Tickets = new List<Ticket>() }



            };
            administrator.ForEach(s => context.Administrators.AddOrUpdate(p => p.AdminID, s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Views\User\Create.cshtml

```
@model RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
        </div>

        <p> <input type="submit" value="Create" />
   </p>

    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

User.cs

```
public class User
    {

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

        [Column("FirstName")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName; }
        }
        public int AdministratorID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AdministratorID")]
        public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }

        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }


        public int DepotID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
        public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }

        public int TicketID { get; set; }
        //Setting up relationships A use can apply for any number of tickets, so Tickets is defined as a collection of Ticket entities.
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Users { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Looks like your Nuget packages may have issues. Does the file entityframework.powershell.utility.dll exist in your packages folder? You may need to reinstall EF.  You can delete migrations and recreate them if needed, but make sure EF is installed correctly first.

Comment: I've reinstalled my packages and intalled EntityFramework and Microsoft ASP.NET Identity EntityFramework. I executed enable-migrations -contexttypename IssueContext -Force and overwritten files. Now i have this error saying "Two output file names resolved to the same output path:"obj\Debug\NameOfSolution.Migrations.InistialCreate.resources" Do you know where I can change it?

Comment: Shouldn't need -Force. Try deleting the Migrations folder and __MigrationHistory and starting over. If you've got seed code in the Configuration class - save that first.

Comment: @SteveGreene wait I forgot to put in my configuration file for the seed methods.

Comment: @SteveGreene So I ran enable-migrations -contexttypename IssueContext (Looks fine) Creates a Configuration and InitialCreate files then I replaced the Configuration code with my original code . Used `update-database` an error pops up! Look at the question i've updated it with the image.

Comment: Can't see the top of the error message. It would also be good to see the Seed() code if that is where it is bombing. You can try running the migration without the Seed() code first, then adding the Seed() code back in since everytime you run update-database Seed() will execute even if no migratons are pending.

Comment: @SteveGreene Would using 2 databases for separate context(AccountsContext storing username and passwords) and IssueContext causes this sort of problem? I've updated the code with the Seed()